# App inventor, Mysql y roles

Tags: php, mysql, app

Resulta que  estoy trasteando con mi app, pero me ocurre lo siguiente:

en mi aplicacion hay usuarios y admin que acceden a ella, pero en el menu de la app los usuarios ven las mismas cosas que los administradores. lo que quiero es crear roles, pero no se como hacerlo.

en la imagen se ve claramente que los diferentes usuarios les he creado los roles marcados por Administrador con la letra A y los usuarios con la U

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el menu indico lo que ve cada cual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para conectar la app con la base de datos uso un PHP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estos son los bloques que tienen el screen llamado Loging

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

llevo atascado en este paso ya un tiempo y no veo nada por internet que pueda guiarme un poco...

perdon el php es

introducir el código aquí

```
> "<?php
// Juan Antonio Villalpando.
// KIO4.COM
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// 1.- IDENTIFICACION nombre de la base, del usuario, clave y servidor
$db_host="localhost";
 $db_name="hchabot_app"; 
$db_login="********"; 
$db_pswd="********"; 

// 2.- CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS
$link = new mysqli($db_host, $db_login, $db_pswd, $db_name);

// 3.- COMPROBAR SI EXISTE ESA PAREJA DE NOMBRE - CLAVE -ROLL
$datos=$_GET;

$Nombre=$datos['Nombre'];
$Clave=$datos['Clave'];
$ROLL=$datos['ROLL'];

////////////////////////////// CONSULTAR /////////
// Juan Antonio Villalpando.
// KIO4.COM

$res=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT nombre,clave,ROLL FROM                          `usuarios_datos` WHERE                                `nombre`='$Nombre'         AND `clave`='$Clave' AND `ROLL`='$ROLL' ");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if( $count >= 1 ) { // Si hay 1 o m?s Juan - 1234, es que el usuario y         clave                existen.
echo 'REGISTRADO';
} else {
echo 'NO EXISTE';
}
?>
```

mysqli_close($link);

?>"

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código como texto y no como imagen. Saludos.

Comment: perdon. tratare de hacerlo, aunque los bloques no se como sacarlos en texto al igual que lo de la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

yo te recomendaría que tuvieras una página para el administrador y otra para los usuarios, que básicamente seria con la misma pagina que usas solo que pondrías cuales cosas quieres que le aparezca a cada uno, es solo una sugerencia.

Comment: y como lo hago?

Comment: Con sesiones, es como una cuenta para cada usuario con diferente rol. Un vídeo que te puede ayudar tal vez puede ser este: https://youtu.be/IAL6Nq6FW0s